# Флеш-память и перезапись

Tags: файловая-система, flash-память

Если создать в ФС на флеш-накопителе небольшой файл (в пределах 1 КБ, например) и перезаписать, скажем, 100000 раз, испортится ли сектор памяти? Если ответ положительный, испортится ли весь накопитель? Интересует также, какие ФС решают эту проблему.

Также другой вопрос - какие существуют технологии обеспечения равномерного использования флеш-памяти?

Было бы здорово увидеть ответы тех, кто сталкивался с подобными вопросами на практике.

Answer (score 0):

> перезаписать, скажем, 100000 раз, испортится ли сектор памяти?

До недавнего времени существовали 2 типа флеш-памяти:

1. С ресурсом 1 миллион перезаписей
2. С ресурсом 100 тысяч перезаписей

Первые обычно применялись как отдельно стоящие микросхемы, обычно с последовательным интерфейсом типа I2C для хранения медленно изменяющихся параметров.

Вторые применялись в составе микроконтроллеров для хранения программы и (возможно) параметров.

Прогресс идет и я его не особо отслеживаю. Возможно, что появились уже флешки с ресурсом 10 миллионов. А может быть и нет. Чтобы точно узнать попробуйте погуглить.

Таким образом, ресурс зависит от типа памяти. Если Вы пропишите память с ресурсом миллион  записей миллион раз, то с большой долей вероятности она испортится.

Еще надо учесть, что прописывать надо разной информацией. Часто в микросхемах стоит компаратор и физически запись сектора не производится, если записываемая информация такая же, которая уже лежит в секторе.

> Также другой вопрос - какие существуют технологии обеспечения
>   равномерного использования флеш-памяти?

Городские легенды говорят нам, что в последних версиях Windows и Linux ОС знает про SSD и якобы ФС для SSD размазывает информацию так, чтобы сектора изнашивались равномерно. Так ли это на самом деле неизвестно, хотя в случае Linux теоретически можно поглядеть текст драйвера.

Comment: Насчёт эволюции флеш-памяти - боюсь, ситуация обратная. По данным из некоторых источников раньше флеш-память строилась на базе SLC (порядка 100 тысяч перезаписей), но сейчас такую днём с огнём не найти. Обычно встречаются MLC и TLC, однако их ресурс гораздо меньше (в пределах 10 тысяч).

Comment: @Андрей Сейчас лень искать, но когда я с этим активно работал, то флешки-миллионники точно были. Вряд-ли их сняли с производства.

Comment: было бы здорово. Хотя сейчас погуглил - у Arduino EEPROM держит миллион перезаписей. Слегка дополнил вопрос: при испорченности одного или нескольких секторов откажется ли работать весь накопитель? Хотя, вероятно, зависит от контроллера.

Comment: @Андрей [при испорченности одного или нескольких секторов откажется ли работать весь накопитель?] Вряд-ли аппаратно контроллер откажется работать, какая ему разница? Вот программно драйвер в ОС может отказаться, но тоже вряд-ли. Скорее всего пометит сектор как BAD и будет его обходить.

Comment: Но чтоб пометить сектор, как BAD, нужна память. Или не так?

Comment: @Андрей Память нужна для всего. И чтобы пометить как BAD, и чтобы хранить каталог. Скорее всего как BAD блок помечается как раз в каталоге, а вовсе не в самом блоке. И, кстати, насчет спец. ФС для флешек. В каталог все время пишется информация и он изнашивается гораздо быстрее, чем собственно место под файлами. Не представляю, как можно размазывать каталог по накопителю и тем более переносить его время от времени с места на место.

Answer (score 0):

Технология обеспечения равномерного использования флеш-памяти называется [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling).

Вкратце.  Есть три вида:

1. Wear leveling отсутствует.
2. Динамический. Если файл перезаписывается, то данные записываются не в те же ячейки, а в другие. Данные, которые не изменяются, хранятся в одних и тех же ячейках. Выравнивается износ тех ячеек, в которых хранятся изменяемые данные. Это лучше чем п.1, но хуже, чем п.3.
3. Статический. Не только перезаписываемые данные пишутся в новые ячейки, но и те данные, которые не изменяются время от времени переписываются в другие ячейки, освобождая старые для записи. Тем самым выравнивается износ всех ячеек.

В нормальных ССД (и даже СД-карточках) этим занимается контроллер диска.

> Если создать в ФС на флеш-накопителе небольшой файл (в пределах 1 КБ, например) и перезаписать, скажем, 100000 раз, испортится ли сектор памяти?

На современных носителях - нет. Файл будет записан в 100000 разных секторов. Но если исхитриться и писать в обход контроллера или на старую флешку, тогда может быть и испортится.

Comment: Спасибо. По ссылке как раз ответ на вопрос по поводу ФС.